# Solving nonlinear equations involving expectations

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, na.numerical-analysis, rootfinding

Let $X$ be a random variable and $g(x,y)$ be a function of two variables. Consider the equation
$$
\mathbb{E}_Xg(X,y) = 0 
$$
Are there any specialized techniques for solving such equations (numerically or analytically), beyond e.g. simply treating it as a standard nonlinear equation in $f(y):= \mathbb{E}_Xg(X,y)$? I am imagining settings in which this expectation is difficult or time-consuming to compute, so the function $f$ is not known.

Comment: If you have a concrete problem it would be nice to know it. Otherwise this question seems to be too general.

Comment: I am indeed interested in the general case. If there are particular solutions for specific assumptions on $X$ and/or $g$, then I'd be curious to see these solutions, but I am not interested in any specific form. Maybe I'll tag this as a reference-request since it's not really about a specific problem.